# How are IP addresses assigned in a Wifi ad-hoc network?

Tags: wireless-networking

When connecting two devices with Wifi in ad-hoc mode is there a standard way of assigning IP addresses?  E.g. is DHCP used, static addresses, or link local addresses?  How would one device know the IP of the other?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual connection method itself, it has to do with the router/gateway settings.  Think of running a CAT-5 cable to a router as the same thing as connecting via Wi-Fi with respect to the overall communication scheme.  All you do is send/receive packets from a router, and the router handles the routing (thus explaining the name...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it however you want. If you want to make one node a DHCP server, you can do that. If you want to assign each node an IP address manually, you can do that.

As for how one device would know the IP address of the other, it depends on why that node would need to know. How do you know someone's phone number? Well, if they're someone you know personally, you ask them. If they're a business, you look it up by their business name. And so on. Similarly, for every reason you might want to know an IP address, there should be a corresponding way you find it out.